# Pandas - handle inf and NaN in one line

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to get rid of both `inf` and `NaN`s in my series.

If I do:

```
df['Iprod'] = df['PD']/df['PF'].replace(np.inf, 0).fillna(0)
```

`Inf` is gone, but not `NaN`.

Is there a one liner to fill `NaN` as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding ()

```
df['Iprod'] = (df['PD']/df['PF']).replace(np.inf, 0).fillna(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df.replace([np.nan, np.inf, -np.inf], 0, inplace=True)
```